# im2bw matlab in java?

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

im2bw matlab in java?

As I can do this in java **matlab** function, as I can make a function to do this process or if there is already performing this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im2bw does nothing more than a simple thresholding, so unless you already have a library you're working with, you can write a few lines of code to do it faster than you can import a library.

The code would look something like what I've written below, with modifications to handle whatever structure you're using to store the data.

```
public static final int WIDTH = 640;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
public static final int THRESHOLD = 0.5;

public static void main(String args[])
{
  float imInput[][] = new float[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
  boolean imThresh[][]; 
  imThresh = im2bw(imInput);
}

public static boolean[][] im2bw(float input[][])
{
  boolean output[][] = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

  for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++){
      output[i][j] = input[i][j] > THRESHOLD;
    }
  }
  return(output);
}
```